# How do I use GNUPG to create a signed message?

Tags: encryption, gnupg

To better explain I used

`gpg --output encrypt.txt --sign encrypt`

to create an encrypted file that can be decrypted with my public key, but what I would like to do is to output an encrypted message in the following form:

> -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
>   Version: GnuPG v1
>
> mQINBFWUsdsBEAC/XoBBdYE3j41lIGB+FveMXcPrDHpVahBwYbzzgxnKIHyw7RsH
>   eECJ7mGk+/o1l4oXJTCWdFUUIoCgLhERmx5kdft7Jvh3X8NHiKEszApSlAODW2YS
>   UvwsbbMb9/ArevavQJ21Of5v0YBOS9Eb9JnczYmSbjYmewgAqsuF0BK9V1AiAkR1
>   cFn5Ao+cKE0F2oGjS12zCqw2O6z89Mb0eypGMNCMDgHUx30+e5QFzvHCx9A/lO+M
>   vvV19wgLvbjfGAhRwtte2vWHQHoT8xuk97CZfSplyJ6DwZpGoBRgxTEeEpNAN33N
>   nJ5kUgYBjECxP/
>
> -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

Comment: If what you're after is an encrypted message that anyone with access to a key can decrypt, you probably want symmetric encryption - this uses the same key for both encryption and decryption, and the key can be set at the time the message is encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gpg --encrypt --sign --armor -r person@email.com name_of_file
```

you can add a second `-r` (recipient) flag to encrypt it for both you and the intended recipient, so that you can view the file as well.

Comment: After posting the original question I kept on searching and digging through the man pages and eventually found that what I wanted to accomplish could be achieved by executing `gpg --clearsign file_name`

Comment: Glad you got what you wanted!